# Neutral Language Not Detected

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am getting the following Errors in my project but I'm not sure what I did to do this or how exactly to fix the issues

[image]

I went to the link which said `In order to remove this warning, either file(s) or string resource(s) should be qualified with the default language, or the default language should be changed.`. My solution only has the default resx file and I haven't added any other languages. In `WMAppManifest` and in Properties I see that the default language is still `en-US`, and my RESX file still contains the `en-US` key as the `ResourceLanguage` value.

Comment: Do you have a default resx without prefix like en-US? Just resource.resx ?

Comment: Yes, that is how it was already created in the default template I'm using.